# Increaing Randomly Generated Numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I want to generate random integers such that the next generated number is always greater than the previous one.

Assume I start with 3, I want the next to be always greater than 3. And say I generated 5, I want the next to be greater than 5 and so on..

Comment: Is there a top limit or is the next number allowed to be 40,000,000 etc.?

Comment: I would take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: What kind of randomness do you expect? Do you want each integer within the range to be selected with the same probability? Or you just need any increasing number sequences?

Answer (score 4):

This should get you a number that is consistently larger than the previous value. The range is the maximum distance from the previous value that you want the number to be.

```
public getLargerRandom(int previousValue){
    int range = 100; //set to whatever range you want numbers to have

    return random.nextInt(range) + previousValue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rnd = 0;
while (true) {
    rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(rnd +1, Integer.MAX_INT);
    System.out.println("Next random: "+rnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would store the randomly generated number as a variable, then use that as a minimum value for the next generation of numbers.

```
int x = 0;
x = new Random.nextInt(aNumber) + x;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example generates a set of random numbers between a start value and a max value without going over the desired maximum number.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetIncreasingInts(20, 3, 101);
    }

  public static void GetIncreasingInts(int numIntsToGet, int start, int max) {
    if (numIntsToGet > 0 && start >= 0 && max > 0) {
      Random random = new Random();
      int nextStart = start;
      int num = -1;

      for (int index = 0; index < numIntsToGet; index++) {
        if ((max - 1) <= nextStart)
          break;
        else {
          num = nextStart + random.nextInt(max - nextStart);
          nextStart = num;

          System.out.println("Number: " + num);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```